# Isolated Versus Non-Isolated Fixed Point, 2D Dynamics

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

I am trying to understand the classification of fixed points in a dynamical systems context (fixed points of a system of two linear differential equations are places where both $x_1' = x_2' = 0$).

Representing 2D systems as a matrix equation $\vec x'=\matrix A\vec x$, Strogatz classifies fixed points based on $\tau$, the trace of the matrix and $\Delta$, the determinant of the matrix:

- unstable node:                                                 $\tau>\sqrt{4\Delta}$,      $\Delta>0$
- unstable spiral (spiral source):    $\sqrt{4\Delta}>\tau>0$,              $\Delta>0$
- neutrally stable centers:                                $\tau=0$,              $\Delta>0$
- stable spiral (spiral sink):          $-\sqrt{4\Delta}<\tau<0$,             $\Delta>0$
- stable node:                                                      $\tau<-\sqrt{4\Delta}$,  $\Delta>0$
- saddle point:                                                                              $\Delta<0$

However, he is very vague about the boundary cases.  Specifically, what happens on the parabola $\tau^2-4\Delta=0$ and the line $\Delta=0$?

Strogatz mentions that these include star nodes (decoupled systems), degenerate nodes (one unique eigendirection), and nonisolating fixed points.  However, in a later problem, he mentions "isolating fixed points".  What is the difference?

How are all of these nonstandard edge cases classified in terms of $\tau$ and $\Delta$?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An isolated fixed point means that one can construct a region around the fixed point such that no other fixed points lie within.  A nonisolated fixed point is the converse (i.e. there are other fixed points arbitrarily close; in practice, these end up being lines or a plane of fixed points).

As far as classification:

For 2D linear systems (or for linearization *predictions* concerning 2D nonlinear systems):

- if $\Delta<0$:
  Isolated fixed point
  CASE #1: Saddle Point
- if $\Delta=0$:
  Nonisolated fixed points

  - if $\tau<0$:
    CASE #2: Line of Ляпуно́в (Lyapunov) stable fixed points
  - if $\tau=0$:
    CASE #3: Plane of fixed points
  - if $\tau>0$:
    CASE #4: Line of unstable fixed points
- if $\Delta>0$:
  Isolated fixed point

  - if $\tau<-\sqrt{4\Delta}$:
    CASE #5: Stable Node
  - if $\tau=-\sqrt{4\Delta}$:

    - if there are no uniquely determined eigenvectors (both can be anything):
      CASE #6: Stable Star
    - if there is one uniquely determined eigenvector (the other can be anything):
      CASE #7: Stable Degenerate Node
  - if $-\sqrt{4\Delta}<\tau<0$:
    CASE #8: Stable Spiral
  - if $\tau=0$:
    CASE #9: Stable Center
  - if $0<\tau<\sqrt{4\Delta}$:
    CASE #10: Unstable Spiral
  - if $\tau=\sqrt{4\Delta}$:

    - if there are no uniquely determined eigenvectors (both can be anything):
      CASE #11: Unstable Star
    - if there is one uniquely determined eigenvector (the other can be anything):
      CASE #12: Unstable Degenerate Node
  - if $\sqrt{4\Delta}<\tau$:
    CASE #13: Unstable Node

General Notes:

- For 2D linear systems, the above predictions are always accurate.
- For 2D nonlinear systems, when the above are used as predictions:

  - The descriptions are always correct for cases #1, #5, #8, #10, and #13 but can be inaccurate for cases #2, #3, #4, #6, #7, #9, #11, and #12.
  - Ambiguous cases #6, #7, #11, and #12 at least have their stability correctly determined.
  - If the system is conservative, a prediction of case #9 is accurate.